# Android connection to data base to store user login/register details

Tags: android, database, web-services

Im engineer student trying to develop android app for mini project. I have 2 layouts Login and Register. When user enter details and click on login/register button i want to store his data into database. How to do it ?. I mean do i need to connect to database from my android code only or do i need to develop web service which handles all this things. Im confused please someone explain. I tried web services(server side code which is in my laptop)it dint work for me.

Comment: For Your understanding, I am keeping it simple... Create A Php file like login and register and pass the values as post parameters you can pass it by libraries Retrofit is one among them. You can also firebase to store some data if you want agan its too broad to answer this question Do some research about it... There are lot of ways you can do it

Comment: @PraveenSP thank you for your reply. I have one more question . If i'm not using web services, can i connect to DB directly in  my android code . Like how we do in web application development(using JDBC etc..). Can we do in that way also ?

Comment: Yes you can do that ....